# python 3d and multidimensional plots

Tags: matplotlib

What are the different alternatives available for 3D plotting in python matplotlib? I am using scatterplot and would like to know more about other types of 3d plots. I checked the site http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html but could not get effective results as I was not able to interpret results effectively. Please let me know of some good 3D plots. Also I would like to try multidimensional plotting and have heard that scatterplot matrix is very effective. Please give some good examples demonstrating the same.